# In Linq-to-Sql determine which properties are changed after update

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine which fields where changed in a Linq-To-Sql Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378378/how-to-determine-which-fields-where-changed-in-a-linq-to-sql-object)

How to determine which properties are updated when updating an entity object in linq-to-sql like:

```
public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public void UpdateUser(User user)
{
    using (var entity = new CoolEntity())
    {
        user.Name = user.Name + "%";
        entity.SubmitChanges();

        //Now here, I would love to know that "Id" and "LastName" is not changed
        //but the "Name" property of the object is updated. 
    }
}
```

I know it sounds a bit hard, maybe my approach is not a way possible; but this is for the logging structure; since I'll need to log the update details with which properties of the object is updated.

I would love to hear if there's any flag for the properties that'll let me identify the changed.

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378378/how-to-determine-which-fields-where-changed-in-a-linq-to-sql-object

Comment: thanks a lot. I couldn't find it through the words I used. I've flagged it as duplicate.