# Getting modified values dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have got a problem. While updating a row in the table by Linq To Sql,
 I want to know the only  changed fields.
Suppose I have 25 fields in a page but I only updates 3 fields and at the time of updation, I need to get only those 3 fields, it's old value + it's modified or new value.

Can IT be possible in the Linq To Sql.

I was searching the things on internet and have come to know about DB.GetChangeSet() but it just gives me the modified row.

I have checked other questions related to  same  from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378378/how-to-determine-which-fields-where-changed-in-a-linq-to-sql-object) but I did'nt get the way they were using I also tried but it is giving me error "Sequence contains no elements"

I tried in this way::
 where TableClass ObjTbl in the function parameter is the Object containing the new values from the model.

```
public int UpdateDetails(int Id, TableClass ObjTbl)
{               
  using (DataContext DB = new DataContext())
  {
    var Data = DB.TableClass.Where(m => m.PkId ==   Id).FirstOrDefault();
    Data .FirstName = ObjTbl.FirstName;
    Data .MiddleInitials = ObjTbl.MiddleInitials;
    Data .FkClientID = ObjTbl.FkClientID;
    Data .LastName = ObjTbl.LastName;
    DB.SubmitChanges();
    TableClass instance = DB.GetChangeSet().Updates.OfType<TableClass>().Where(m => m.PkId == Id).First();
    DB.TableClass.GetModifiedMembers(instance);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a view model with a clearly defined purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for your changes **before** you call SubmitChanges.

Also, in your example the line

```
TableClass instance = DB.GetChangeSet().Updates.OfType<TableClass>().Where(m => m.PkId == Id).First();
```

will throw an exception if nothing was changed, otherwise it will return the record you are amending ie, Data, so you may as well just do something like

```
 ModifiedMemberInfo[] changes = DB.TableClass.GetModifiedMembers(Data);
```

If nothing has been changed, then this will return an empty array, rather than throw an exception.